# :after pseudo-element working in FF, but not Safari or Chrome

Tags: css, joomla, pseudo-element

I'm trying to add an :after pseudo-class to the .readmore class in Joomla.

```
.readmore
{
  font-size:12px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
  color:#000 !important;
  font-weight:bold;
  display:inline;
}

.readmore:after
{
   content:"";
   display:block;
   width: 215px;
   height: 3px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
   margin:3px 0 3px 0;
}
```

In Firefox, it works perfectly; after the article intro, there's a "...more" link, followed by a line, then the next intro. Safari and Chrome seem to be ignoring the :after element completely.

Edit: I've figured out that it has something to do with the `display:` of `.readmore`. It works in Safari/Chrome if I have both `.readmore` and it's `:after` pseudo- set to `:block`, but then the `.readmore` is on its own line (obviously), and I'd really like it to be inline. If I set it to `:inline` or `:inline-block`, it stops working in Safari/Chrome (but FF doesn't seem to care... it renders the `:after` pseudo- the same no matter what - as a horizontal line that extends across the column). Any tips/advice or resources on how FF/Safari/Chrome render block elements differently?

If this is confusing I'll take some screenshots and post later.

Comment: There is no `...more` in your content declaration, but it works for me in Chrome - http://jsfiddle.net/ncYmC/

Comment: Oh, `...more` is declared elsewhere, in a language file. The :after element is only supposed to be the line (standing in for an <hr />, I suppose).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to achieve the following effect:

There is some text, then there is iniline «more...» text at it's end, and then on the new line there is an block-level element that makes gray stripe.

Example code without :after:

```
This is the example text that we want to show <div>more...</div>
<div class="line"></div>
```

May render like this:

```
This is the example text that 
we want to show more...
-----------------------------
```

If I'm correct, then it's probably Firefox bug, and not the Chrome/Safari.

:before and :after pseudo-classes didn't add element after the tag they applied to, they add one before and after it's contents.

So the example above will render as:

```
This is the example text that we want to show <div>more...<div class="line"></div></div>
```

And from here are all the problems: You can't insert block level element inside inline element, or browser will not know how to render it.

If it was a normal tag, then browsers would try to repair it. For example if you insert **div** tag inside **p** tag like this:

```
<p>1<div>2</div>3</p>
```

And then try to look at the DOM with Firebug you will see that browser closed missed (as it thinks) tags and rendered code as:

```
<p>1</p>
<div>2</div>
<p>3</p>
```

Firefox probably do the same thing with :after element — closed the **div** and then added new element on the same level. But Safari and Chrome tried to render it inside the original class and failed.

So if you want to make it to work, you better attach :after to the parent class of the text snippet, and not to «more...» element. Like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    This is the example text that we want to show <div>more...</div>
</div>

.parent:after { your_code_here }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be better implemented as a template override?

Copy the /component/com_contentviews//category/blog_item.php file (entirely from memory - so likely somewhat wrong but the principal holds) to /templates/yourtemplate/com_content/category/blog_item.php, and edit the php/html to do what you need.