# :after pseudo element not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari, pseudo-element

I have a styled sentence with dynamic text. Sometimes the text is too long, and pushes the anchor at the end outside its box. I want the text to wrap after the `span.price-difference`, but the anchor button to be positioned against the right side of the `p`.

I added an `:after` pseudo element to `.price-difference`. I've got it set `content: ''` and `display: block`. Works in FF, Chrome, IE (including IE8, which I have to support), but not Safari.

There is an easy answer, wrapping the text following `.price-difference` with another `span`, and set it to `block`, but changing the HTML is a hassle, requiring a backend developer to make changes to a JSP file, and I'm hoping to avoid that. Looking for a CSS only solution, if it exists.

```
<p class="upsell"> Upgrade To 
  <span class="stateroom-upgrade"> Concierge Class </span> 
  for an additional 
  <span class="price-difference">$7.14 USD </span> 
  per person per day 
  <a href="" class="ccButtonNew"><span>View Upgrades</span></a>
</p>
```

The CSS

```
.upsell {
  background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px #FAFAFA;
  border-top: 2px dashed #E8E8E8;
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11.5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: auto 19px 5px;
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 8px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 560px;
}

.upsell .price-difference {
  color: #0C82C4;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.stateroom .upsell .price-difference::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.upsell .ccButtonNew {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 17px;
}
```

The `p` element has `white-space: nowrap` set on it, but when I turn it off, the problem doesn't go away.

I think it's related to the following link, but my situation isn't the same. In that question, the asker put a block level element `div` inside a `p`, which only takes inline elements. I have an inline element, `span`, inside the `p`. This *should* work.

[:after pseudo-element working in FF, but not Safari or Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897263/after-pseudo-element-working-in-ff-but-not-safari-or-chrome)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
.stateroom .upsell .price-difference:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000; /* placeholder border */
}
```

try adding a position to the after's css rules. i had a similar situation in which the after pseudo wouldn't display in old versions of safari but worked properly in all other browsers. I fixed adding a position rule to the css.

Hope this hepls.

Comment: That was not an extra colon in the CSS selector, that is actually the proper way of selecting pseudo elements. Web developers do not use that simply because Internet Explorer 8 does not support the CSS3 syntax, only the CSS2.1 syntax.

Comment: This helped me to properly align a pure css arrow consisting of pseudo elements in a button tag in Safari (iPhone 5 to be precise). Using both margins and the left attribute I was able to get it right. +1

Comment: I just got the error in Firefox 55. First time in stumble upon this but thanks!