# after pseudo background overlay not showing in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, pseudo-element

This is an issue only on Safari not showing a transparent overlay on top of a background image, it works fine in all other browsers. I've had a look through other suggested questions and even tried a fix from this one: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057154/after-pseudo-element-not-working-in-safari][1] however that didn't fix it.

So I simply have a relatively positioned container that has a background image on it, a child div that is absolute positioned which has a transparent background colour that covers over the background, then finally some content that sits over both.

Here is a basic example of what I need and what is working in all but Safari:

```css
section {
  background-image:url('https://www.encompasscorporation.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/example-background.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

section:after {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(0 0 0 / 60%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

section h1 {
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>
    Example content
  </h1>
</section>
```

In Safari the dark overlay doesn't work so the white text on a light background is almost impossible to read and same with black on dark backgrounds.

Anyone else had this issue or can help please?

Comment: What version of Safari are you running? Your demo works in my Safari.

Comment: This is the annoying thing, I don't have a Mac, I've only received a forwarded screenshot from a team member which originally came from a different user of the site who sent a screenshot from Safari, so I'm really limited with tools/info. Could you check to see if you can see the light overlay on this image and the dark text okay? https://safehavenbolton.co.uk/  thanks

Comment: Use Browser Prefixes: Safari sometimes requires vendor prefixes for certain CSS properties. For example, you might need to use -webkit-background for specific background-related properties. Check if using these prefixes resolves the issue.

Comment: Some versions of Safari struggle with background-attachment: fixed. See https://caniuse.com/?search=background-attachment%3A%20fixed If you could find the version of Safari and the OS that is causing the problem that might help track things down.

Comment: Your website looks OK on my iPad, latest version of Safari.

Comment: Thanks Howarth for the information, still trying to get that info but if worst comes to worst, I could simplify it and bake the overlay effect into the images themselves. More work obviously but less risk of issues. Cheers